# Uninstalled an application but the store shows it as still installed. How can I reinstall it?

Tags: apps, store, insider-preview

I updated to the latest Windows Phone 10 Technical preview. In the process I lost all of the application data that I had stored on my SD card and need to reinstall my apps. I removed the applications from my phone but now when I go to install the applications from the store again it won't let me as it still thinks the application is installed.

Comment: This could just be another bug, report it via the feedback app?

Comment: Try doing a soft reset, this should reset your store cache. I found it's usually a good idea to do a hard reset after upgrading to Windows 10 mobile preview. This should definitely fix all app install issues.

Comment: Try Check for updates in Store and Restart the phone.